# htaccess redirect subdirectory to root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

What rule can I add .htaccess that would give me the following result?

I want to redirect to the homepage any search that includes a certain directory. For example, when anyone tries...

```
test.com/example
...or...
test.com/example/something
...they end up at...
test.com
```

Most everything I have tried kinda worked but always ends up appending whatever was after the targeted directory to the domain after the redirect, for example...

```
test.com/example/something
...leads to...
test.com/something
```

This is not what I want. Thanks

Code I have tried...

```
RewriteRule ^example/(.*)$ http://www.test.com [L,R=301]
and
Redirect 301 /example http://www.test.com
```

UPDATE
This seems to fix it...

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/example/ /
Redirect 301 /example http://www.test.com/
```

Thanks!

Comment: Post the actual code you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^example/ / [L,R=301]
```

or

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/example/ /
```

Comment: Code that worked added to the original question. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @ChadSeay You shouldn't need the `Redirect` line. That's the same as `RedirectMatch` but without regex.